# Using document.elementFromPoint to get the position of all elements with a certain class and then alert the Left and Top positions

Tags: javascript, jquery, position

Hello for my project i need to get the positions of all .move elements and check if there is an element at relative position.

Here's the HTML code :

```
<article id="move_wrapper">
    <div class="move">
        <span class="location"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="move">
        <span class="location"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="move">
        <span class="location"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="move">
        <span class="location"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="move">
        <span class="location"></span>
    </div>
</article>
```

And here's the JS code:

```
function overlap() {<br>
    $(".move").click(function () {
        $("#main *.move").each(function () {
            var thisPosLeft = this.position().left;
            var thisPosTop = this.position().top;
            var elem = document.elementFromPoint(thisPosLeft - 100, thisPosTop - 100);
        });
        alert(elem.index(this));
    });

}
```

Here's a jsfiddle with the full code:
http://jsfiddle.net/C3uqV/

Comment: `elem` is a dom object, can't use jQuery methods directly on a dom object

Comment: and `elem` is declared within a the each.